# CI failed before execute the .gitlab-ci.yml file on gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new to gitlab CI.

My .gitlab-ci.yml file is

```
stages:
  - build

my_simple_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello, GitLab CI/CD!"
  tags:
    - my_tag
```

I had tried to activate the .gitlab-ci.yml by gitlab-ci-local and it work perfectly. The output is:

```
Using fallback git user.email
Using fallback git user.name
parsing and downloads finished in 24 ms
my_simple_job starting shell (build)
my_simple_job $ echo "Hello, GitLab CI/CD!"
my_simple_job > Hello, GitLab CI/CD!
my_simple_job finished in 7.43 ms

 PASS  my_simple_job
pipeline finished in 223 ms
```

However, on the gitlab, it seems the process failed before executing .gitlab-ci.yml file.

[image: the log in gitlab]

(for search engine friendly, here is the log of my gitlab)

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.4.0 (44444444)
  on dddddddddddddd-mmm-mmmm.local 7777777-N
Preparing the "shell" executor
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
Running on dddddddddddddd-mmm-mmm.local...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/dddddddddddddd/builds/7777777-N/0/dddd/dddd/.git/
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I don't have the admin permission (yes, this is my task assigned by my company). How can I find out or fix the problem?

Comment: The information you have redacted would probably provide some info. One think I can think of is the runner being Windows machine.

Comment: "Windows machine" do you mean the runner is on the windows OS? It is on Mac.

Comment: I don't see the issue then. Put the thing to public gitlab, show it is working, then push the exact same repo to your company gitlab and if it is not working there, just send it with link to both company and public repo to your gitlab admin.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I see the issue, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem.

On the terminal, input this command:

`echo 'unset cd'>>~/.bash_profile; source ~/.bash_profile`

Problem solved.

p.s.:

For checking the gitlab-runner log, run
`gitlab-runner --debug run` on the gitlab server would help.

reference:
[Gitlab CI runner job failed exit status 1 when changing directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49444879/gitlab-ci-runner-job-failed-exit-status-1-when-changing-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `tags` section, GitLab CI uses tags to

> to select a specific runner from the list of all runners that are available for the project.

Source [Official `.gitlab-ci.yml` keyword reference for `tags`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags)

Comment: I think(because I don't have the permission to check the runner) We use the tags to point the runner. I had checked to remove/change the tags and the ci won't execute anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is related to the Git strategy used by your runner *(as it is a Shell executor)* to fetch the project. You can try to switch from `git fetch` to `git clone` strategy as shown below:

- Got to your repo, then Settings -> CI/CD -> General pipelines  -> Git strategy
- Choose `git clone`
- Save the changes

[image]

---

*Note that this workaround can be costly in a production use case as it will clone the repository on each job.*